# How to get the carrier code name on windows phone?

Tags: carrier

I know how to get the carrier name by using this: DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator
But, how to get the carrier code name ?

Example: the carrier code name of Vietel Corporation (Viettel Mobile) is: 45204